# API versioning at BackEnd - Declare the versioning(v1) at global level or at each controller/method level?

Tags: architecture, api, api-design

If I keep versioning at the global level then it would save the clutter at each controller level,

```js
// main.js
main() {
 registerGlobalRoutesPrefix("/api/v1");
}

// controller1.js
@Route("controller1-route")
class controller1 {

 @Route("my-api-route")
 myApi() {
 // do something
 }
}
```

Here all controllers don't need to maintain the versioning themselves.

But what if I need to add another method *for another version(v2)*, how can I expose that endpoint with "v1" set at the global level?

Now, most of the sample examples I've seen, use the global approach, so how do they handle this problem?

Comment: You probably need to provide more context such as which framework you are using, what the purpose of versioning is in your context, etc. Right now, there is a lot of missing information for someone to be able to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to answer this is to zoom out and consider the perspective of a user of the API.  If a user integrated with your API, would they expect to have one version of the API to code against or 14 different versions depending on which end point they are coding against.  Once they receive a customer ID from version 4 of search, can they use that to get customer information from v14 of the customer API?

Also consider the API's volatility (likelyhood to change) and the types of changes that might occur.  Once an API passes the first 3 months of serious usage, API changes typically start to slow down.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found is to keep *separate release branches for each API version*.

Example:
I may have the following branches:- master(latest v4), v3, v2, v1.

So, here whenever a new version change is introduced,

- simply checkout a new branch from the current latest branch
- make changes to the function
- deploy/merge it as the latest(v5) branch

Now, a tool like Load Balancer can route the request to a specific deployed code as per the version being passed in the URL.